# How to replace Ctrl + c by a nicer hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

How can I replace `Ctrl + c` by some handier hotkey (especially on the German keyboard `Strg + c` are far apart)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
2. Open an IDE or simply the (Text) Editor and write...

> $^::Send, ^c

3. Save the file with extension .ahk
4. Manually start the .ahk-file by double-clicking it and/or paste it to your AutoStart-folder if you want it to start automatically together with windows

What this tiny script does is to copy the current selection to the clipboard upon pressing [^] by forwarding the (in)famous [Ctrl] + [c] standard hotkey.

Enjoy ☺